# Is there a plugin that will let you do actions by mail?

Tags: email

I want to be able to trigger different Wordpress actions by mail.

So for example maybe if a send a mail with the word "publish" in the subject and a post id in the content it will publish the post with this id, or if i will send a mail with the words "delete user" in the subject and a user id in the content it will delete that user and so on...

Answer (score 1):

As far as deleting users from an email, I've never heard of that.

You can however publish posts via WP's built in Post By Email feature.

Go to your admin > Settings > Writing and fill out the required mail server settings and login fields.

> To post to WordPress by email you must set up a secret email account with POP3 access. Any mail received at this address will be posted, so it’s a good idea to keep this address very secret.

However, this lacks many of the common features of posting from the admin.  You can use [a plugin that extends](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postie/) this functionality.

Comment: Thanks. that's a great plugin! it might be helpful for some of my needs. the direction i was thinking about is more of a dynamic plugin that will let you sign specific actions to specific words in mail or shortcodes in mail or so... but thanks! guess i will have to create that kind of a plugin if i don't find one :)